# Apache: Automatic log splitting per Virtual Host?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, logging, httpd

Whenever we create new Virtual Hosts on our dev servers, we always have to manually specify separate access and error logs:

```
ErrorLog logs/mysite/dev1-error.log
CustomLog logs/mysite/dev1-access.log "common"
```

Is there anyway to make Apache automatically split up the logs instead of having to specify them every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel your pain, as a web developer I have probably over 200 vhosts in my local dev - I personally don't care about the logs & log them all to the main /var/log/apache...

However what I did do was to write a shell script to add/manage all my vhosts - all you need to do is to tweak it to write logs to wherever you like...

```
#!/bin/bash
ARGS=1
if [ "$1"X = "X" ];
        then
        echo "Must enter domain name"
        exit 0
fi
if [ "$2"X = "X" ];
        then
        echo "Must enter domain suffix"
        exit 0
fi
if [ "$3"X = "X" ];
        then
        echo "you must type "restart" if you want apache restarted "no" if not!"
        exit 0
fi

domain=$1.$2;

#echo $domain;
#exit 0


rm $domain.conf

echo "<VirtualHost *:80>" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        ServerAdmin no-reply@network.local" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        ServerName $1.network.local" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        DocumentRoot /Data/vhome/$1.$2/httpdocs" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        HostnameLookups Off" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        UseCanonicalName Off" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        ServerSignature On" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Data/vhome/$1.$2/cgi-bin/"" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log combined" >> $domain.conf;
echo "    <Directory "/Data/vhome/$1.$2/cgi-bin">" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        AllowOverride All" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        Options +ExecCGI -Includes" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        Order allow,deny" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        Allow from all" >> $domain.conf;
echo "    </Directory>" >> $domain.conf;
echo "    <Directory "/Data/vhome/$1.$2/httpdocs">" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        AllowOverride All" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        Order allow,deny" >> $domain.conf;
echo "        Allow from all" >> $domain.conf;
echo "    </Directory>" >> $domain.conf;
echo "       # #XSS prevention" >> $domain.conf;
echo "       # RewriteEngine On" >> $domain.conf;
echo "       # RewriteCond %(REQUEST_METHOD) ^TRACE" >> $domain.conf;
echo "       # RewriteRule .* -[F]" >> $domain.conf;
echo "</VirtualHost>" >> $domain.conf;

if [ "$3" = "restart" ];
        then
        rcapache2 restart;
fi

chmod 666 $domain.conf

cat $domain.conf
echo "Created!";

exit 0
```

Hope it helps.

-sean

Comment: Looks nice, I will try it out. I assume you have to run this script in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` ?

Comment: no I have it in my /etc/apache/vhosts/ - if you move it, just change your paths, or possibly add a path parameter pointing to the apache includes directory... If you wanted to get it real sexy, you could also have it create the virtual host directory structure & jack a cname into your nameserver configs....

Comment: You could clean that up using a big here document. Variable expansions are still processed inside.

Comment: +1 for MikeyB, those hundred echos hurt my eyes :-P

Answer (score 2):

Back when I still used apache, I learned a trick from a coworker. He piped the global access log through an `awk` script. The `awk` script in turn would then take care creating the different logfiles.

In httpd.conf:

```
LogFormat "%V %p %a %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%200{Referer}i\" \"%200{User-agent}i\" \"%{cookie}n\"" awklogpipe
CustomLog "|/usr/local/bin/apacheawklogpipe" awklogpipe env=!dontlog
```

The script /usr/local/bin/apacheawklogpipe:

```
#!/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
        months["Jan"] = "01";
        months["Feb"] = "02";
        months["Mar"] = "03";
        months["Apr"] = "04";
        months["May"] = "05";
        months["Jun"] = "06";
        months["Jul"] = "07";
        months["Aug"] = "08";
        months["Sep"] = "09";
        months["Oct"] = "10";
        months["Nov"] = "11";
        months["Dec"] = "12";
}

{
        # HEADS UP: SET THIS!!!!
        LOGBASE="/var/log/httpd/access"

        SSL=""

        # Automagicly set first 
        SITE=tolower($1);
        PORT=$2

        if ($2 == 443)
        {
                SSL="-ssl"
        }

        # Extract all but first two fields (vhostname vhostport to be exactly) into LINE
        LINE=substr($0,index($0,$3));

        # No matter where it is, we will find an apache datestamp.
        match(LINE,/\[[0-9]+\/[A-Z][a-z]+\/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+[\t ]+[+-][0-9]+\]/);
        split(substr(LINE,RSTART + 1,RLENGTH - 2), ap_log_time, /[\/: ]/);

        #ap_rotatelog= LOGBASE "/" SITE ":" PORT "/access-log" SSL "-" ap_log_time[3] "-" months[ap_log_time[2]] ap_log_time[1];
        ap_rotatelog= LOGBASE "/" SITE  "/access_log" SSL;
        if (system("test -d " LOGBASE "/" SITE ) == 0)
        {
                print LINE >> ap_rotatelog;
                close(ap_rotatelog);
        }
        else
        {
                print SITE "\t" SSL "\t" LINE >> LOGBASE "/w3logrotate-error.log";
                close(LOGBASE "/w3logrotate-error.log");
        }
}
```

Make sure /usr/local/bin/apacheawklogpipe is executable. All you would need to take care of with this script, is create a directory in `/var/log/httpd/access` that corresponds to the virtualhostname. I had a script that would create a virtualhost config and create the log directories.

Comment: You also can use [split-logfile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/other.html) (it can be found in `support` folder when compiling from source) or [vlogger](http://n0rp.chemlab.org/vlogger/) to do this.

Comment: very nice solution....

Answer (score 2):

Another options. Don't split them in httpd.conf. Instead, log everything to your main Access Log, and then split them later with a program like [split-logfile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/other.html). This helps to simplify your log configuration.

This is described at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#virtualhost

> By adding
>   information on the virtual host to the log format string, it is
>   possible to log all hosts to the same log, and later split the log
>   into individual files. For example, consider the following directives.
>
> ```
> LogFormat "%v %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" comonvhost CustomLog
> logs/access_log comonvhost
> ```
>
> The %v is used to log the name of the virtual host that is serving the
>   request. Then a program like [split-logfile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/other.html) can be used to post-process
>   the access log in order to split it into one file per virtual host.

Comment: That sounds like a nightmare. If I have 30 active sites and I want to look through the log for a single site I have to either sift through a HUGE log file or split it out everytime? Not to mention running a `tail -f` would suck horribly... No thanks.

Comment: To each his own. I wouldn't want 2x30 logfiles sitting around, and this works well with [Simple dynamic virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/mass.html#simple). The idea here is to handle log processing afterwards. `tail -f access_log | grep www.example.org` works well enough. So does a a central syslog/Splunk server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at [mod_macro](http://www.cri.ensmp.fr/~coelho/mod_macro/). This has a more general approach, but I guess that this could help you otherwise as well.